# Kineticjs Html5 cant effect image object in other different layer in same stage?

Tags: html, canvas, layer, kineticjs

I can't resize or rotate different layer in same stage , it change the size or rotation but it does not effect immediately ,

If you want to see use this link : 
http://clients.rafineri.net/test/canvas/canvasTest.php

**Scripts in the page source**

Just use slider and then click on the image to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At end of both functions (**updateResize()** and **updateRotate()**) insert the line

```
image.getLayer().draw(); /*redraws layer*/
```

To draw the image when page loads,  call layer.draw() inside **InitStage()**

```
layer.draw(); /*add this line in initStage()*/
stage.draw();
```

Comment: Your comment completly fix my problem,
thanks mate!